# Can I redirect visible traffics from Burp Suite to Fiddler?

Tags: android, reverse-proxy, fiddler, burp

I am doing some reverse api works on android app. As time goes by, some apps ignore Fiddler Certificate, so I have to change another software like burp suite since it can capture more traffics in my android device.

Now I am going to make a middle interface between my android app and the server programmatically but Burp Suite does not support that.

That's why it would be better if I can redirect traffics from Burp Suite to Fiddler.

Can anyone know how to address it?

Thanks so much.

Comment: The certificates generated by Fiddler classic can be problematic in combination with modern Android or iOS versions. There is an add-on that installs a different certificate generation system that should work with Android: https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/add-ons search for `CertMaker for iOS and Android` to get `fiddlercertmaker.exe`. Afterwards you can select it in the HTTPS interception dialog as cert source.

Comment: Hi Robert, it sounds like a usefull add-on, I will try that. Anyways, as you were saying, there is indeed something wrong with Fiddler's certificate. I managed to make it work like a charm by restarting root certificate in Fiddler, so now I don't need to manually modify request in Burp Suite. I still leave the question here in case anyone has a idea to redirect traffics between those.

Comment: Typically you can configure an "upstream proxy" in interception proxies like Fiddler, Mitmproxy, .. I don't know if this is also possible with Burp but I assume so.

Comment: Well, maybe "upstream proxy" what I am looking for. I am going to give it a shot. Thanks so much Robert.